# Xamarin app won't publish to apple store - multiple ERROR ITMS-90045 errors

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac

I have a Xamarin Forms app that was last published using Xamarin Studio in 2017.  The app builds error free using Visual Studio 2017 and runs fine when an iPhone is connected to the Mac.  When I try to publish it to the Apple store I get numerous

> ERROR ITMS-90045: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements" saying they are
>   not supported on iOS such as UILaunchStoryboardName,
>   NSCameraUsageDescription, NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription,
>   CFBundleIdentified, MinimumOSVersion, etc..

I created new certificates and profiles without success. 
There are no duplicate keys in `Info.plist` and the multiple Info.plist files in the IPA are all unique. 
All the keys that are in error can be found in Info.plist. The iOS Bundle Signing points to the new Provisioning Profile that I created.  The certificates in the KeyChain have not expired.

Here are two screen shots of the Info.plist dropdown list of available properties.  In my app I don't have the correct list [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJIWJ.jpg).  I'm assuming this is why it is erroring out.  In a new test app [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5oVI.jpg), the list is correct.

Comment: Are you using any third-party SDK in your project? Usually this is seen when you have multiple Info.plist files in your bundle.

Comment: So do I delete the others?